# If G is regular of order n, then $\alpha (G)\leq n/2$.

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove above statement, but not sure where to start. I know that independence number and vertex cover number add up to n, and we have lower bound $ n/(\Delta+1) $ on the vertex cover number. I have tried induction, but don't know what to do when G is not bipartite. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: $\alpha (G) $ is independence number and $\Delta $ is the maximum degree.

Comment: What is $\alpha(G)$? It would also help if you clarify any other notation, such as $\Delta$.

Comment: Clarified,  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set with more than $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices. Suppose that $S$ is independent. Then there would be $k|S|$ edges in $G$ incident to a vertex in $S$ (check to make sure you see why). This is more than $\frac{kn}{2}$ though, which is the total number of edges $G$ has (check to make sure you see why).

This is your answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I have been overthinking with induction and edge covers. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $G$ is $k$-regular. Then $G$ has $\frac{kn}{2}$ edges.

Now find a maximum independent vertex set $A$, which by definition has $|A|=\alpha(G)$. Every edge associated with any vertex in $A$ is not shared with any other vertex in the set, so there are $k|A|$ distinct edges associated with $A$. Naturally $k|A| \le \frac{kn}{2}$ giving the result, provided only that $k>0$ (i.e. that $G$ has some edges).

Comment: I see @Mike has answered in a similar way, but through contradiction, so I'll leave this here for contrast.

Comment: @bof, agreed, k>0 is a requirement